# Using HTTP Angular

Tags: http, angular

I'm trying to make a simple HTTP request using Angular, but I keep getting this error:

> Property 'http' does not exist on type 'WorksService'.

```
import {Injectable}     from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable}     from 'rxjs/Observable';

export class Work {

  constructor(public id: number, public name: string) { }

}


@Injectable()
export class WorksService {

 constructor (private http: Http) {}

 private _WorksUrl = 'api/projects';  // URL to web api

 getHeroes () {
  return this.http.get(this._WorksUrl)
                .map(res => <Work[]> res.json().data)
                .catch(this.handleError);
 }
 private handleError (error: Response) {
   // instead of just logging it to the console
   console.error(error);
   return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you creating `WorksService`? Where does the object come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you instantiate the service by your own. You need to get it through dependency injection so Angular2 will provide the `http` instance directly.

To do that, just add the service in providers either when bootstrapping your application or within the `providers` attribute of the component that uses the service (directly or indirectly).

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ HTTP_PROVIDERS, WorksService ]);
```

or

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ HTTP_PROVIDERS ]);

(...)

@Component({
  (...)
  providers: [ WorksService ]
})
export class SomeComponent {}
```

To inject it then, you do like this:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private service WorksService) {
    this.service.getHeroes().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        (...)
      });
  }
}
```